# Selecting records where relation is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a one-to-many relationship between Product and ProductCategory.

How do I query all productcategories that have at least one product associated to them?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :product_category
end

class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ProductCategory.all(
  :joins => :products, 
  :select => "product_categories.*, count(products.id) as prod_count",
  :group => "product_categories.id"
)
```

I found out how to solve this thanks to the great Ryan Bates on this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins

Answer (score 4):

`ProductCategory.includes(:products).where('products.id is not null').all`

Comment: This answer works. The problem is the products collection will be loaded even if you don't want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Joins makes an inner join, so the where clause in some of the other answers is superfluous.  Grouping by products.id as some others do will repeat the category when the category has multiple products, grouping by the ProductCategory will eliminate dups.

```
ProductCategory.joins(:products).group('product_categories.id')
```

Comment: This does not seem to satisfy the condition of only returning a `ProductCategory` if it has at least on `Product` in it.

Comment: As I noted about, Joins makes an inner join.  Therefore .joins(:products) means an inner join with the products table, which by definition only returns results with records in products.  This is why the where clause in the other answers is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more readable solution:

```
ProductCategory.joins(:products).where('product_categories.id is not null').group('products.id')
```